# Cannot get python 2.7 tkinter text editor find function to work

Tags: string, python-2.7, tkinter, text-editor, tk-toolkit

recently I have been working on a GUI python plain text editor.  The code calls this function

```
def Find():
    win = Toplevel() 
    Label(win, text="Find:").pack()
    e1 = Entry(win)
    e1.pack()
    Button(win, text="Find Me!!!!", command=win.destroy).pack()
    targetfind = e1.get()
    print targetfind
    if targetfind:
        where = textPad.search(targetfind, INSERT, END)
        if where:
            print where
            pastit = where + ('+%dc' % len(targetfind))
            #self.text.tag_remove(SEL, '1.0', END)
            textPad.tag_add(SEL, where, pastit)
            textPad.mark_set(INSERT, pastit)
            textPad.see(INSERT)
            textPad.focus()
```

However, I cannot get it to work.  I have searched the internet looking for anything that might help me implement a find feature, but I have not succeeded in finding one that works.  Any help in implementing  a find feature would be very much appreciated.

I am using python 2.7.7, Tkinter, and I am running this on Windows 7. 
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because you create `e1`, and then a nanosecond later, do `targetfind = e1.get()`. The user does not have the reflexes to type a query in that nanosecond. All of your code starting with `targetfind = e1.get()` needs to be in a function which gets executed as the `command` of your "Find" button.

```
def Find():
    def find_button_pressed():
        targetfind = e1.get()
        print targetfind
        if targetfind:
            where = textPad.search(targetfind, INSERT, END)
            if where:
                print where
                pastit = where + ('+%dc' % len(targetfind))
                #self.text.tag_remove(SEL, '1.0', END)
                textPad.tag_add(SEL, where, pastit)
                textPad.mark_set(INSERT, pastit)
                textPad.see(INSERT)
                textPad.focus()
        win.destroy()
    win = Toplevel() 
    Label(win, text="Find:").pack()
    e1 = Entry(win)
    e1.pack()
    Button(win, text="Find Me!!!!", command=find_button_pressed).pack()
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer works, it is clear, and it is well explained.  If I had enough reputation I would up vote it.